# How can I use Bugsense to catch exceptions in specific code?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, bugsense

Ive added BugSense to my Windows Phone app and modified the app.xaml.cs accordingly.  However, I know some users are experiencing crashes but BugSense is not seeing it. BugSense to see new sessions and what not so i know the license is correct.

I believe the crashing occurs within this code, particularly with webclient I think. What do can I add to this code so that if something occurs, BugSense will report it?

```
 private void LongListSelector_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        LongListSelector selector = sender as LongListSelector;

        // verifying our sender is actually a LongListSelector
        if (selector == null)
            return;

        SoundData data = selector.SelectedItem as SoundData;

        // verifying our sender is actually SoundData
        if (data == null)
            return;


        if (data.IsDownloaded)
        {
            this.PlaySound(IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication().OpenFile(data.SavePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read));
        }
        else
        {
            if (!SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<INetworkService>().IsConnectionAvailable)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You need an internet connection to download this sound.");
            }
            else
            {
                WebClient client = new WebClient();

                client.DownloadProgressChanged += (senderClient, args) =>
                    {
                        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                            {
                                data.DownloadProgress = args.ProgressPercentage;
                            });
                    };

                client.OpenReadCompleted += (senderClient, args) =>
                {
                    using (IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication().CreateFile(data.SavePath))
                    {
                        args.Result.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                        args.Result.CopyTo(fileStream);

                        this.PlaySound(fileStream);
                        data.Status = DownloadStatus.Downloaded;
                    }

                    args.Result.Close();
                };

                client.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(data.FilePath));
                data.Status = DownloadStatus.Downloading;
            }
        }

        selector.SelectedItem = null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just started using BugSense myself in my WP8 app and I've very impressed how it catches unhandled exceptions without anything more than the single line of code in my App.xaml.cs file:

```
public App()
{
    BugSenseHandler.Instance.InitAndStartSession(new ExceptionManager(Current), RootFrame, "YourBugSenseApiKey");
    ...
}
```

So from my experience BugSense should be catching these exceptions for you without any extra code on your part.

How do you know about these crashes? Is it from the Windows Phone Dev Center? If so then you might still be seeing crashes reported from users that have an older version of your app installed before you added BugSense.

I find that checking for a new app version from within the app itself on start-up and alerting the user is a great was to keep people up-to-date. Many users might not visit the Windows Phone Store for extended periods of time and even then may not bother to update your app to the latest version so there's a good chance you have a lot of users on old versions.

Comment: After some direct feedback from a few users, I'm starting to suspect that WP8 users are affected and not WP8.1 users. The app was set up as a WP8 version. I have 8.1 and have no issues. So something in the code about is causing crashing for WP8 users, I suspect. To your point, I do have that code in my app.xaml.cs and bigsense isn't catching it.  If my assumption is correct, I need to find out what in my code isn't working in WP8 and what to do about it.

Comment: I see errors logged from both WP8 and WP8.1 for my WP8 app. Have you exported your stack traces from your Windows Dev Center - https://dev.windowsphone.com/en-US/CrashReport ("Export top stack traces from the last 30 days" link above graph) - to see if indeed there's stack traces there that are being missed by BugSense?

Comment: Yes. There are few hundred there. And I have to believe people who leave reviews or email me saying the app crashes. BugSense would give me more detail I think and at least confirm what OS version they're using. I wish I had WP 8 on a spare phone so I could test it. Though is there perhaps a way to change the emulator OS version in Visual Studio to use 8 instead of 8.1?

Comment: Well, I dont know why Bugsense didnt pick it up. But I did confirm a crash occurs myself by downloading the WP 8 Emulator. Strange why BugSense doesnt see it though.